# Adding new cells to table with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I add a new cell to my table using Javascript? The text entered to the **bowlersName** should be the text for the new cell.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!--  HEADER 1 & 2  -->
<h1>Central Valley Lanes</h1>
<h2>2008 Bowling Teams</h2>


Bowler's name <input type="text" name="bowlersName" size="15" /><input type="button" value="Add Bowler" />
<h2>Team Roster</h2>
<form action="FormProcessor.html" method="get">
<table border="1" id="bowlerList">
<tr><td id="empty">Your team roster is empty</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Submit Roster" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you can use jquery to add cells based on the input.
Something like this should work:

```
var NewName = $("#bowlersName").val();
jQuery("#bowlerList tr").First().Before( "<tr><td>" + NewName "</td></tr>");
```

What this does is first finds the table then finds the tr elements of the table. From those elements it finds the first tr element and adds the new cell before it. This would flow top to bottom, as in the newest element would be on top where as the oldest would be at the bottom.

To get a left to right type use this:

```
jQuery("#bowlerList tr").First().Append( "<td>" + NewName + "</td>");
```

Take a look at this site for a complete explanation of the code:
http://api.jquery.com/

Also if you want to remove the cell saying you have no bowlers this could work:

```
jQuery("#empty").remove();
```

Comment: @Johnson Look up the jQuery functions he used and write your own! It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
td.innerText = "Your new row text";
document.getElementById("bowlerList").appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: I actually have a question about this particular way of doing things. Is there anyway to accomplish the jquery.before() method using this idea? I am under the impression that the pure dom traversal could be faster in certain circumstances.

Comment: Of course. `var table = document.getElementById("bowlerList");` `table.insertBefore(tr, table.firstChild);`

Comment: ok I was more looking to see if indeed the insertBefore behaved as I thought it did. Thank you for the clarifications.